# Is it possible to return a feedback error, but still allow wicket to update the component models?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket form which contains many TextField input components. There's a Validator attached to most of these inputs.

Suppose I've entered 50 values, and one of those fails a range validator. Wicket then generates an error feedback message, but also does not update the models associated with each component. Result is that I lose all 50 values I just entered, and have to type them in again.

My question is, can I tell Wicket to update the models of those components which had valid values, but just report an error for the bad value?

Digging around in the framwork, I noticed this code fragment in FormComponent, which seems to be indicating that if there is an error, then don't update the model.

```
public final void processInput()
{
    inputChanged();
    validate();
    if (hasErrorMessage())
    {
        invalid();
    }
    else
    {
        valid();
        updateModel();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to customise this behaviour, and achieve my aim of retaining all valid values?

Comment: What kind of validators are you using? User input should be kept, even if there are validation errors. Can you please show one of those validators, how is it attached to `FormComponents`, and how form submission is handled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd bet that `FormComponent.processInput()` is not being called at all here. When you submit the `Form`, [`Form.process()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.java#Form.process%28%29) gets called. There, it will call [`Form.validate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.java#Form.validate%28%29), which in turn will call [`Form.validateComponents()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.java#Form.validateComponents%28%29), ultimately using `FormComponent.validate()`.

The problem you're having here is the global handling in `Form.process()`. The form submits fully, or not at all. When a `FormComponent.validate()` fails, `Form.hasError()` will return `true`, and therefore `Form.process()` will never update any of the models.

You could:

- Move all FormComponent independent validations to a `FormValidator`. There you can choose to update the Models of those `FormComponents` that pass their validations.
- Implement `Form.onError()` and use a visitor there to update the models of valid `FormComponents`.
- Override `Form.process()` and modify the [`// If a validation error occurred`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.4.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.java#974) branch to use your own methods to mark components as valid/invalid, and update (or not) model objects, depending on the `FormComponent` having errors. `FormComponent.hasErrorMessage()` will tell you if validation failed on a certain `FormComponent`.

---

**UPDATE**

After discussing the reasons why user input was lost with the OP, it turned out that the `FormComponents` were being added in a `ListView` that did not have `setReuseItems` set to `true`. This was causing `FormComponents` to be created anew on each `ListView.populateItem()`, therefore losing all user input.

More information on the nature of this problem can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/listview-and-other-repeaters.html#ListViewandotherrepeaters-Usingformcomponentsinarepeater):

> There are however a few provisions you have to take care of when using 
>   a repeater in the form. Usually repeaters clear out their items at the 
>   beginning of every request, when inside a form this is usually 
>   undesirable because you want to preserve the old items because you 
>   want them to keep their state as opposed to being recreated fresh.
>
> For example, if you use ListView, you should call 
>   ListView.setReuseItems(true) inside the form so that it preserves old 
>   items instead of always creating new ones everytime.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the page here is a DynamicWizardStep.

Comment: I haven't used wizards, but I don't think that makes a difference. It will be enclosed in a `<form>` anyway, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will be Xavi, but it's kind of hidden, which I guess is the intent of using the DynamicWizard (wicket extensions).

Comment: What I don't see is why are components losing user input. We can try to discuss this in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4665/is-it-possible-to-return-a-feedback-error-but-still-allow-wicket-to-update-the-c) if you feel like it.